# Reformulate a problem with concave objective function into a QP

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I would like to convert this problem into a QP (Quadratic program).

$$\text{Maximize } \sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{N}log2(1+p_{kn}b_{kn})\\
\text{subject to } \sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{n=1}^{N}p_{kn}\leq P_{0}\\
p_{kn}\geq 0, \forall k,n$$

The variables are $p_{kn}, \forall k,n$
Since the optimization variables are continuous and are inside the logarithm function, I was unable to convert it into a QP. Can you help me to resolve this issue please?

Comment: What makes you think it would be possible to convert this to a QP?

Comment: The solver I'm using is limiting me to use only QP formulation. So, I'm still hoping to find a way to convert it.

Comment: That's not really a reason to believe that this will be possible.  You should consider using a more general solver.

Comment: Assuming your cost factors $b_{kn}$ are positive, this is at least a convex problem, posed on a convex domain (a simplex). That should be a relatively easy problem to solve.